How to assign credit on Drupal.org to a GitLab user whose name is not a link?
I received a helpful review comment on an issue I am working on for a module I maintain, so I want to credit the user.
The issue is on Drupal.org, and the user made the comment on GitLab.
Usually, I assign credit on Drupal.org at the bottom of the issue page where it lets you tick checkboxes for the people who have made comments on the issue.  However, the user who left the comment is not listed there.  In addition, the user's username is gray (not a link), so I can't click it for more info.
When I enter the user's username in the Credit others field on the issue page, no user is found.
Going to www.drupal.org/u/username doesn't work, either.
How do I credit this user?
Details: The user is GeneralBouLi on this issue
EDIT: If you visit the linked issue now, the user's name has become a link.  This only happened AFTER I added the username in the Credit others field as described in the accepted answer.

On the comment posted on GitLab, there is the link to the GitLab account.



The Gitlab Account, on the right side, under Contact, contains the link to the drupal.org user profile.



On the drupal.org account, you can see the username is jérôme dehorter.



On projects where I can credit other people (for example, Drupal.org site moderators), it is sufficient I enter jérôme dehorter (and click on Save) to get that person credited. The Credit others field autocompletes the username, confirming that is the correct one.



